# Drush with a dockerized Drupal install

Tags: 7, drush

I'm trying to setup a development environment for Drupal using docker.

I've already succeeded on creating a PostgreSQL container and a Drupal container using official images for both, and I can replicate the production environment.

How do I get drush to detect my Drupal install?

I've tried both https://hub.docker.com/r/drush/drush/ and https://github.com/DockerDemos/appstack-drush (had to build that last one) but when I run drush inside the containers they don't see the Drupal install.

I run "docker run --volumes-from `<my-drupal-container>` --link `<my-db-container>`:postgres -it drush/drush dd" and it shows nothing, "drush cc" finds no caches.

Comment: You have to specify a working directory `-w`. See Docker docs.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things you can do here:

1. Use Docker as external container like you are doing. You need to pass the --net parameter too to make that work, see example below. You will always use this drush container as a running command, not a container that is up and running with your stack all the time.

`docker run --net={your_container_network_name} --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app drush/drush sqlc`

2. Simply add drush to your Drupal container and connect to that container to run drush commands:

Dockerfile:

```
ENV DRUSH_VERSION 8.1.2
RUN curl -L --silent https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/${DRUSH_VERSION}/drush.phar \
  > /usr/local/bin/drush && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Connect to your container and then run any drush command inside it:

```
docker exec -it {container_id} bash

root@{container_id}:/var/www/html# drush status
```

Comment: Option 2 worked well for me.

Comment: `docker exec -it -w /var/www/html {container_id} drush status` in one line. `docker exec -it -w /var/www/html {container_id} bash -c "drush status"` probably works, too.

Answer (score 2):

For the --uri parameter, pass in whatever URI you use to access your site from your local web browser.  In addition to --uri, you must also specify --root, which should contain the full path to the Drupal root inside your container.

Answer (score 0):

To have a very convenient way to use drush / drupal console / composer in Docker, I use zsh with [autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) and a little function for each command.

In each drupal project folders, create a `.autoenv.zsh` file the following settings:

```
autostash DRUSH_IN_DOCKER=1
autostash DOCKER_PHP_CONTAINER=myproject_fpm_1
autostash PROJECT_URL=http://www.mydomain
```

Then creates a small zsh function:

```
drush() {
    if [ "$DRUSH_IN_DOCKER" == "1" ]; then
        docker exec -it ${DOCKER_PHP_CONTAINER} /var/www/vendor/bin/drush --root=/var/www/web --uri=${PROJECT_URL} "$@"
    else
        drush "$@"
    fi
}
```

Be sure to replace the provided paths with the one of your drupal project in docker.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
docker-compose exec php sh
drush cc all
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Rather than just giving 2 commands, could you explain what these commands do?

Comment: The exec command executes a program on the passed container (php). 'sh' is just a basic (non-bash) shell, which is available on most containers. So this comment is just telling you to connect to the container, which is no different than Karel's comment, except with less explanation.